# Adding the backend port to ZAP scope

Tags: zap

I am pentesting an Angular application backed by a .NET 5 app. They run both on localhost. This is my very first experience with [OWASP Zed Attack Proxy](https://owasp.org/www-project-zap/)

I can add `http://localhost:4200` to ZAP scope, but ZAP can't seem to find `https://localhost:5001` which is the Kestrel backend

- **Question**: how can I add manually a site to the scope from the HUD?
- **Question**: is it meaningful to add a REST backend to ZAP scope for active scanning?

The answer to the second may likely be yes as it could be testing for SQL injection tokens at least.

The site tree contains only the following

```
[-] Sites
[+] https://aadcdn.msftauth.net
[+] https://login.live.com
[+] https://aadcdn.msauth.net
[+] https://clients1.google.com
[+] https://update.googleapis.com
[+] http://127.0.0.1:50144
[+] https://dc.services.visualstudio.com
[+] https://login.microsoftonline.com
[+] http://localhost:4200
[+] https://accounts.google.com
```

Note, port 50144 looks like ZAP server itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the browser make any requests directly to the Kestrel backend? If not then ZAP will not know about it.

You should add test any related backend if you are able to. Do you have an  API definition? ZAP can import SOAP, OpenAPI/Swagger, GraphQL...

Comment: The browser made direct request to port 5001 because of Angular services. I can see them in F12 when I run the application stand alone, but I didn't mind checking when running inside ZAP. I have an API definition with Swagger

Comment: ZAP should see and show everything that is proxied from the browser. You should definitely import the Swagger definition, but thats not supported by the HUD yet so you will need to use the ZAP desktop. TBH its worth using the ZAP desktop in many cases. The HUD is great if you want to focus more on the application but once you start looking at it in detail the desktop will provide you with lots more options.